# catkin_make --pkg <package> alternative

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am using ROS kinetic and got an already finished ROS project build with catkin_make. My job is to add and edit some nodes in this project. The problem is, that I do not have the source files to every node (some of them are right protected, so the previous developer deleted the src folder of some nodes). If I put an CATKIN_IGNORE file in these node folders and then do catkin_make, they cannot be started after I restarted the PC.

So after some googling I found the option catkin_make --pkg . And that has seem to be working good. But after a while it didn't just build the given pkg, it was just like the normal catkin_make and started to build all packages (which obviously failed, because of the missing src).

Is there a fix for this problem or another solution beside catkin_make --pkg for my problem?

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302602/catkin_make---pkg-%3Cpackage%3E-alternative/) by [reloaded](https://answers.ros.org/users/37350/reloaded/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, it would be beneficial if you describe your layout in more detail.

---

**Assumption**

I'm answering now on the following assumption:

```
~/catkin_ws
     |-> build
     |-> devel
     |-> src
           |-> pkgA
                  |-> no src folder available
           |-> pkgB
                 |-> src (etc.) available
```

You got this workspace in a compiled state and you `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` to use it. `pkgA` is the one where the `src` has been deleted and thus cannot be compiled. The compiled binaries do reside in `devel`, though. You want to adapt `pkgB`.

---

**Solution to your problem**

The solution is actually pretty simple. Leave the `~/catkin_ws` alone and use [workspace chaining](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces).
In detail:

```
mkdir -p ~/my_catkin_ws/src                 # create a new workspace
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash         # source the old one
cd ~/my_catkin_ws
catkin_make                                 # compile the new one
source ~/my_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash      # now use the chained workspaces.
```

Then put a copy of `pkgB` (you do have the sources of this one) and any new packages you create into `my_catkin_ws/src`. Call `catkin_make` only in your new workspace.
This allows you to use this `pkgB` and the `pkgA` of `~/catkin_ws`.

---

**What the other guy should have done**

Don't pass around compiled workspaces, this makes no sense and is very error prone.
You could, though install to a good place using `catkin_make install` (right install rules provided) and pass this directory around.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [reloaded](https://answers.ros.org/users/37350/reloaded/) on 2018-09-07**:
sorry for being imprecise, I'm new to ROS and don't know what is exactly needed.
Your assumption was right, that is my layout.
Thanks for the help and the quick answer, it worked fine for me.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-07**:
happy to hear that!